# Show that $\text{Var}[N]\approx cn^2$ for large $n$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Consider coupons numbered $1, 2, ..., n,$ which you collect until you
> have all numbers. Each time you get a coupon, its number is
> independent of previous numbers and all numbers are equally likely.
> Let $N$ be the number of coupons you need, and show that
>
> **(a)** $\mathbb E[N] = n\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{k} \sim n\log n$ for large $n$,
>
> **(b)** there is a constant c such that $\operatorname{Var}[N] \sim cn^2$ for large $n$. What is $c$?

The problem **(a)** is already solved in [another post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772873/show-that-n-sum-k-1n-frac1k-sim-n-logn-collectors-problem/2772932?noredirect=1#comment5720526_2772932), I just included it in case it's needed to be referred to in order to solve **(b)**.

Attempt: We know that

$$\text{Var}[N]=\text{Var}[X_1+X_2+...+X_n]=\text{Var}[X_1]+\text{Var}[X_2]+...+\text{Var}[X_n].$$

From **(a)** [we got](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2772873/show-that-n-sum-k-1n-frac1k-sim-n-logn-collectors-problem/2772932?noredirect=1#comment5720526_2772932) that $X_k\sim \text{geom}(\frac{n-k+1}{n}).$ This means that

$$\text{Var}[X_k]=\frac{1-\frac{n-k+1}{n}}{\left(\frac{n-k+1}{n}\right)^2}=\frac{(1-k)n}{n-k+1}.$$

And finally

$$\text{Var}[N]=n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1-k}{n-k+1}.$$

Here I'm stuck. I'm not even sure that this is correct because the sum seems quite hard to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't simplified the variance of $X_k$ properly: it should be
$$ \frac{(k-1)n}{(n-k+1)^2} = \frac{n^2}{(n-k+1)^2} - \frac{n}{(n-k+1)}. $$
Then
$$ \frac{\operatorname{Var}{[N]}}{n^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{(n-k+1)^2} - \frac{1}{n(n-k+1)} = \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r^2} - \frac{1}{nr}, $$
putting $k=n-r+1$. The first term converges to $\pi^2/6$, while the second term is $\sim -(\log{n})/n$ by comparing with an integral.

Comment: Thank you. But how did you split the first fraction into two partial fractions?

Comment: $$ \frac{k-1}{(n-k+1)^2} = \frac{-(n-k+1)+n}{(n-k+1)^2} $$